# EF context is not thread safe, why don't make it thread safe by design?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I often find some methods in some API are not thread safe. For example, let consider the EF context. Here is the warning I can quote from asp.net core tutorial:

> An EF context is not thread safe: don't try to do multiple operations in parallel. When you call any `async` EF method, always use the `await` keyword.

## Questions

Generally, the thread safeness of a method is decided by design or it is a mistake that is spotted later on? For the EF context above, why don't make it thread safe?

Comment: Because it's incredibly complicated to do? Who knows, this can only be answered with opinion anyway.

Comment: I think this question must be addressed to authors of EF. My opinion: because thread safety have cost.

Comment: Of course it's not thread safe, you create a DbContext to which changes to the models are tracked.  If you make changes in multiple threads, how do you propose that it knows what to save and when, for example when it's performing updates in multiple threads?  The DbContext is essentially throw away.

Comment: If you need parallel operation make another one context and let the storage make magic for you. If you know a way how to do parallel with one context you must organize all access to context yourself. It difficult and risky.

Comment: It's not thread safe and it can't be. It performs async operations, so the main thread is not blocked. If you don't use await, you will try to do parallel programming, which is not thread safe. That's the only thing the warning is trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

In general make mutable datastructure thread-safe is very hard and has negative impact on single threaded use cases.

Often is required different (more complex) api to do the changes (i.e. [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) vs. [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (which can't really be answered anyway) and because it now has upvotes, the question can't be automatically deleted. Please don't answer things like this.

Comment: @DavidG That sounds reasonably. But the question is not bad and imho deservers answers (not mine only).

Comment: But the question is demonstrably bad for Stack Overflow, that's why it has been closedand has 3 downvotes. Answering this question only serves to encourage users to post off topic questions and wastes your time doing so. Wouldn't you rather be answering good quality questions instead?

Comment: @DavidG Ok. Where should be asked this kind of questions?

Comment: Any site that doesn't have the rules we have here. Quora, Microsoft forums, perhaps even the GitHub repos for EF. I don't know, I just care about what is on this site.